# Eclipse Save-to-Server Performance since Summer 15

Tags: eclipse, performance, deployment, summer-15

We've been experiencing significant Save to Server issues from Eclipse. We filed a case, and Tier 3 made a change to our platform schema, but the problems continue. Is anyone else seeing severely degraded Save to Service performance since Summer 15 (early/mid June)? We're trying to raise it up as a known issue, but need confirmed reports from additional customers and/or partners.

Comment: are you using the latest Eclipse IDE with Tooling API support?

Answer (score 1):

[There is](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69959/metadatatoolingapi-access-on-cs14-extremly-slow-no-support/70774#70774) explained the performance of sandbox.

We have the same problem with cs17.

Comment: I confirm CS17 but also, sometimes, CS18